# Get HTML data from webpage after X seconds in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm fetching data from the tesla used inventory, to program a price checker to find prices that fit a user's given budget. However, the Tesla webpage only loads the cars after a certain period of time, and when I use requests to fetch the html data, it doesn't load that. Is there a way to get the HTML data after some period of time, once all of it is loaded? This is the page I'm scraping: https://www.tesla.com/inventory/used/m3 (The url params change based on the user's input, so that's why I'm not including them. When I'm accessing the page, I do include the zip code and other parameters).

Comment: You can use a web-driver like selenium https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score -2):

From the sound of your question you've already got the HTML scraping handled and your really after how you can do the delay before executing the next lines of code.

The simple answer is you can put python to sleep.

```
import time
time.sleep(5) # equivalent to 5 seconds
```